# Problem with masking S3 url and adding to CDN

Tags: url, amazon-s3, storage, masking, bucket

I have object storage S3 this is not AWS but another S3.

I'm trying to do url masking or add to CDN like Cloudflare however this is not possible due to the bucket name. Storage automatically adds some digits with id and the ":" character to the bucket. It looks like this:

```
s3.objectstorage.com/11111111111111111111:bucket/file
```

And this is the name of my bucket: `11111111111111111111:bucket`

With this character `:` I can't add the bucket name to DNS. 
Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: I don't understand how this is related to DNS. Can you explain what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: It's about the CNAME record https://tonyredhead.com/amazon-s3/mask-s3-url

Comment: The DNS portion of that URL is `s3.objectstoreage.com` (basically everything before the slash). Therefore, it is not possible to convert this particular URL to a unique URL that refers to your bucket. Which S3-compatible service are you using? They will likely have a DNS name that puts the bucket at the _front_ so that it is part of the URL name, such as `BUCKETNAME.s3.objectstorage.com`.

Comment: *"this is not AWS but another S3."*  There's only one S3 and that's Amazon Simple Storage Service, so asking a question about "another S3" simply does not make sense.  What's the actual name of this other object store service?

Comment: Object Storage only uses Path style, it is not possible to use Virtual-Hosted. So probably can't mask url by record cname. Topic rather to close unless someone can do miracles. Regards